# How to implement an efficient bidirectional hash table?

Tags: python, hashtable, bidirectional

Python `dict` is a very useful data-structure:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

d['a'] # get 1
```

Sometimes you'd also like to index by values.

```
d[1] # get 'a'
```

Which is the most efficient way to implement this data-structure? Any official recommend way to do it?

Comment: If you prefer, we can assume that values are immutable as well as keys are.

Comment: What would you return for this dict: {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'A' : 1 }

Comment: @PaulMcGuire : I would return `{1: ['a', 'A'], 2: 'b'}`. See my answer for such a way to do it.

Comment: Note to moderator: this is **not** a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map. The latter has 1) very vague wording 2) no MCVE 3) only deals with the case of the bijective map (see first comment in this question), which is a lot more restrictive than this actual question, which is more general. So I think marking it as duplicate is here, in this particular case, misleading. If really one should be a duplicate of another, it should be the contrary as this one here covers the general case whereas the other (see answers) doesn't cover the non-bijective case.

Comment: @Basj It should return `{1: {'a', 'A'}, 2: 'b'}`

Comment: This question is more than ten years old, but I am reading it for the first time now.  You might find inspiration in the Java library Google Guava.  They have a class `HashBiMap` that is worth reading.  (I assume a similar structure could be implemented in Python.)  The documentation clearly outlines edge cases and how they are handled.  Ref: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java

Answer (score 106):

Here is a class for a bidirectional `dict`, inspired by [Finding key from value in Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657457/finding-key-from-value-in-python-dictionar) and modified to allow the following 2) and 3).

Note that :

- 1. The *inverse directory* `bd.inverse` auto-updates itself when the standard dict `bd` is modified.
- 2. The *inverse directory* `bd.inverse[value]` is always a **list** of `key` such that `bd[key] == value`.
- 3. Unlike the `bidict` module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict, here we can have 2 keys having same value, this is *very important*.

**Code:**

```
class bidict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(bidict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.inverse = {}
        for key, value in self.items():
            self.inverse.setdefault(value, []).append(key) 

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            self.inverse[self[key]].remove(key) 
        super(bidict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.inverse.setdefault(value, []).append(key)        

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.inverse.setdefault(self[key], []).remove(key)
        if self[key] in self.inverse and not self.inverse[self[key]]: 
            del self.inverse[self[key]]
        super(bidict, self).__delitem__(key)
```

**Usage example:**

```
bd = bidict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})  
print(bd)                     # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}                 
print(bd.inverse)             # {1: ['a'], 2: ['b']}
bd['c'] = 1                   # Now two keys have the same value (= 1)
print(bd)                     # {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
print(bd.inverse)             # {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b']}
del bd['c']
print(bd)                     # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(bd.inverse)             # {1: ['a'], 2: ['b']}
del bd['a']
print(bd)                     # {'b': 2}
print(bd.inverse)             # {2: ['b']}
bd['b'] = 3
print(bd)                     # {'b': 3}
print(bd.inverse)             # {2: [], 3: ['b']}
```

Comment: Very neat solution of the ambiguous case!

Comment: I think this data structure is very useful in many practical problems.

Comment: **This is phenomenal.** It's succinct; it's self-documenting; it's reasonably efficient; it just works. My only quibble would be to optimize the repeated lookups of `self[key]` in `__delitem__()` with a single `value = self[key]` assignment reused for such lookups. But... _yeah._ That's negligible. Thanks for the pure awesome, [Basj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422096/basj)!

Comment: How about a Python 3 version?

Comment: Have you tried this code in Py3 yet, @zelusp ? I didn't spot any issues on a quick scan through it.

Comment: I did @TheNate. I get error `AttributeError: 'bidict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` when running `bd = bidict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})`

Comment: Ah. Right. Try it without "iter" and it should work.

Comment: I like this answer for the example. The accepted answer is correct still and I think the accepted answer should stay as the accepted answer, but this is a little bit more explicit for defining it yourself, merely because it clearly lays out that in order to reverse the dictionary you must place the reverse's values into a list since there cannot be a one-to-one mapping because a dictionary has a one-to-many relationship with key-to-values.

Comment: Can this be packaged into bidict?

Comment: this doesn't support many to many in both directions. bd = bidict({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]}) errors about unhashable type.

Comment: This breaks when using `bd.pop(some_key, None)`

Comment: I wrote my own BiDict based on what i've seen here and without {key -> key} issue. Also my implementation has same methods and behavior, that you expect from a dict. Please ping me here if you find some uncovered cases: https://gist.github.com/titovanton/2225805da5ccdd788349bbf7f1eef1a8

Comment: Will this get inefficient if we have a large number of keys with the same value then set some of these to different values? Would replacing the lists in inverse with sets solve this?

Comment: Nice solution!
I was just wondering if it is really desiderable to possibly have an empty list as value in the inverse dict after a key in the original dict changed its value ( I am referring to the last three lines in the usage example here).
Would'nt it be better to check for that in  __setitem__? 
`if self.inverse[self[key]] == []: del self.inverse[self[key]]`

Comment: I would use sets instead of lists in the inverse dictionary.

Comment: Also breaks with `bd.clear()`; that doesn't go through `__delitem__`

Answer (score 55):

You can use the same dict itself by adding key,value pair in reverse order.

```
d={'a':1,'b':2}
revd=dict([reversed(i) for i in d.items()])
d.update(revd)
```

Comment: +1 A nice, practical solution. Another way to write it: `d.update( dict((d[k], k) for k in d) )`.

Comment: +1 For neat use of reversed().  I'm undecided if it's more readable than the explicit `dict((v, k) for (k, v) in d.items())`.  In any case, you can pass pairs directly to .update: `d.update(reversed(i) for i in d.items())`.

Comment: Note this fails e.g. for `d={'a':1, 'b':2, 1: 'b'}`

Comment: No, it doesn't for me.

Comment: Slight modification: `dict(map(reversed, a_dict.items()))`.

Comment: This fails for `d={'a':1,'b':2, 'c': 1}`.

Comment: @0xc0de Nope, afterwards `d[1] = 'a'` overwrites the original `d[1] = 'b'`

Comment: **Adding reverse mappings to the original dictionary is an awful idea.** As the above comments demonstrate, doing so is _not_ safe in the general case.  Just maintain two separate dictionaries. Since the first two lines of this answer ignoring the trailing `d.update(revd)` are great, however, I'm still contemplating an upvote. _Let's give this some thought._

Comment: the fact that it fails in the above cases is not related to the implementation. It is implicit that in a bidirectional structure as described in question, you cannot have duplicate values/keys (as they are accessed in same way). Keeping two dictionaries (in any form) corresponds to the limitation of not having duplicate values or duplicate keys (but you can have same values in both keys and values). In this case `={'a':1, 'b':2, 1: 'b'}` succeeds, while `d={'a':1,'b':2, 'c': 1}` still fails, because not a matter of implementation.

Comment: In many cases, keys and values reside in different namespaces. Then, this is a good solution. One just has to be aware of that.

Comment: Idea is awful ONLY IF your dictionary has such cases. If one is looking for such data structure s/he already knows the limitations and the data probably doesn't have such cases. Searching for perfection will only waste your time if such simple solutions suffice.

Comment: A clearer way of writing this would use a dictionary comprehension: `revd = {j: i for i, j in d.items()}`

Answer (score 45):

A poor man's bidirectional hash table would be to use just two dictionaries (these are highly tuned datastructures already).

There is also a [bidict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict) package on the index:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict

The source for bidict can be found on github:

- https://github.com/jab/bidict

Comment: 2 dicts requires double inserts and deletes.

Comment: @Robuts, didn't understand you.

Comment: @Juanjo: nearly any bidirectional/reversible hash table will involve "double inserts and deletes", either as part of implementing the structure, or as part of using it.  Keeping two indexes is really the only fast way to do it, AFAIK.

Comment: Of course; I meant that take care of the 2 index by hand is the problem.

Comment: No, `bidict` is not really usable : Try :

    `from bidict import bidict`
    `mybidict = bidict({'a': 'value1', 'b': 'value1'})`
    `print mybidict['a']`   => this leads to a `KeyError` because duplicate values are not accepted :(

Comment: @Basj I think it's correct that it's not accepted since having more than one value means it's not a bijection anymore and is ambiguous for the reverse lookup.

Comment: I don't really agree @user193130 : I think limiting the usage of bidict to injections and bijections is a bit too restrictive... Here in my previous example, using math notations, we could see `f^{-1}('value1')` as the set `{a, b}`.

Comment: @Basj Well, I can understand that there would be use cases which would be useful to have more than one value per key, so maybe this type of data structure should exist as a subclass of bidict. However, since a normal dict maps to a single object, I think it makes much more sense for the reverse to be the same as well. (Just to clarify, although the value can be a collection too, I meant that the key of the first dict should be of the same type as the value of the reverse dict)

Comment: the link is outdated :(

Comment: @tscizzle https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict should work as should `pip install bidict`, https://github.com/jab/bidict, and https://bidict.readthedocs.org.

Comment: A one to one datastructure or (bimap) would be as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map Hence a 1 value maps to a key. And 1 key maps to a value. Making this less strict, one can extend this to allow multiple keys pointing to 1 value, but 1 value can only point to 1 key. And then loosening up even more would allow multikeys to multivalues. An example of the latter is to use 2 dicts mapping keys/values to sets of values/keys.

Comment: This is what I did. I have no inserts or deletes, so it's easy enough to make two.

Answer (score 8):

The below snippet of code implements an invertible (bijective) map:

```
class BijectionError(Exception):
    """Must set a unique value in a BijectiveMap."""

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        msg = 'The value "{}" is already in the mapping.'
        super().__init__(msg.format(value))


class BijectiveMap(dict):
    """Invertible map."""

    def __init__(self, inverse=None):
        if inverse is None:
            inverse = self.__class__(inverse=self)
        self.inverse = inverse

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value in self.inverse:
            raise BijectionError(value)

        self.inverse._set_item(value, key)
        self._set_item(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.inverse._del_item(self[key])
        self._del_item(key)

    def _del_item(self, key):
        super().__delitem__(key)

    def _set_item(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

The advantage of this implementation is that the `inverse` attribute of a `BijectiveMap` is again a `BijectiveMap`. Therefore you can do things like:

```
>>> foo = BijectiveMap()
>>> foo['steve'] = 42
>>> foo.inverse
{42: 'steve'}
>>> foo.inverse.inverse
{'steve': 42}
>>> foo.inverse.inverse is foo
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```
import itertools

class BidirDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), **kwargs):
        self.update(iterable, **kwargs)
    def update(self, iterable=(), **kwargs):
        if hasattr(iterable, 'iteritems'):
            iterable = iterable.iteritems()
        for (key, value) in itertools.chain(iterable, kwargs.iteritems()):
            self[key] = value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            del self[key]
        if value in self:
            del self[value]
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        dict.__setitem__(self, value, key)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        value = self[key]
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        dict.__delitem__(self, value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (type(self).__name__, dict.__repr__(self))
```

You have to decide what you want to happen if more than one key has a given value; the bidirectionality of a given pair could easily be clobbered by some later pair you inserted. I implemented one possible choice.

---

**Example :**

```
bd = BidirDict({'a': 'myvalue1', 'b': 'myvalue2', 'c': 'myvalue2'})
print bd['myvalue1']   # a
print bd['myvalue2']   # b
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem, but using the above implementation, wouldn't there be issues if the keys and values overlapped? So `dict([('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]); dict['b']` -> `'c'` instead of the key `'a'`.

Comment: It's not an issue for the OP's example, but might be a good disclaimer to include.

Comment: How can we do that `print bd['myvalue2']` answers `b, c` (or `[b, c]`, or `(b, c)`, or anything else) ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure the key to value mapping is one to one, otherwise, it is not possible to build a bidirectional map.

Second, how large is the dataset? If there is not much data, just use 2 separate maps, and update both of them when updating. Or better, use an existing solution like [Bidict](https://github.com/jab/bidict), which is just a wrapper of 2 dicts, with updating/deletion built in.

But if the dataset is large, and maintaining 2 dicts is not desirable:

- If both key and value are numeric, consider the possibility of using 
  Interpolation to approximate the mapping. If the vast majority of the
  key-value pairs can be covered by the mapping function (and its
  reverse function), then you only need to record the outliers in maps.
- If most of access is uni-directional (key->value), then it is totally
  ok to build the reverse map incrementally, to trade time for
  space.

Code:

```
d = {1: "one", 2: "two" }
reverse = {}

def get_key_by_value(v):
    if v not in reverse:
        for _k, _v in d.items():
           if _v == v:
               reverse[_v] = _k
               break
    return reverse[v]
```

Answer (score 1):

a better way is convert the dictionary to a list of tuples then sort on a specific tuple field

```
def convert_to_list(dictionary):
    list_of_tuples = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        list_of_tuples.append((key, value))
    return list_of_tuples

def sort_list(list_of_tuples, field):
     return sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: x[field])

dictionary = {'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
list_of_tuples = convert_to_list(dictionary)
print(sort_list(list_of_tuples, 1))
```

output

```
[('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('a', 9)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the highest rated answer, `bidict` does not work.

There are three options:

1. **Subclass dict**:  You can create a subclass of `dict`, but beware.  You need to write custom implementations of`update`, `pop`, `initializer`, `setdefault`.  The `dict` implementations do not call `__setitem__`.  This is why the highest rated answer has issues.
2. **Inherit from UserDict**:  This is just like a dict, except all the routines are made to call correctly.  It uses a dict under the hood, in an item called `data`.  You can read the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict), or [use a simple implementation of a by directional list that works in Python 3](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/#UserList/UserDict:_lists_and_dictionaries_that_are_actually_extensible).  Sorry for not including it verbatim:  I'm unsure of its copyright.
3. **Inherit from Abstract Base Classes**:  Inheriting from [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) will help you get all the correct protocols and implementations for a new class.  This is overkill for a bidirectional dictionary, unless it can also encrypt and cache to a database.

TL;DR -- Use [this](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/#UserList/UserDict:_lists_and_dictionaries_that_are_actually_extensible) for your code.  Read  [Trey Hunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98187/trey-hunner)'s [article](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/) for details.

Comment: Nice article. Still, what exactly does not work with `bidict`?

Comment: What did not work two years ago may or may not work now.

Comment: It did work 2 years ago, it worked with Python 2.x, and it works with Python 3.10 now. Rather than distract with a mistake from whatever testing you did in 2020, it'd be better to focus on what your advice offers which is different since the mention of `UserDict`, etc. is useful and might point someone with more advanced needs in the right direction.