# get keys from specific value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, computer-science

**How can I get all keys which contain the specific value in dictionary?**

> For Example:- This is dictionary which holds simple data.

```
{'h':['123,'4'], 'm':['456':'4'], 'a':['123,'4']}
```

> If I enter a value of 4, prints all the keys which containing the number. **This is the output.**

```
{'h', 'm', 'a'}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? Also note that your output appears to be a *set*, which (like a dictionary) is not an ordered data structure - it's not clear whether you expect that behaviour.

Comment: Looks like that output should be a list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding key from value in Python dictionary:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657457/finding-key-from-value-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: @Tadhg: Not quite the same because that is looking for equality, whereas this is looking for containment.

Comment: ok but the only thing that changes is using `in` instead of `==`

Answer (score 4):

Since your result is a set, I would use a [set constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Since the value of your set depends on an iteration of your input data, I would pass a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to the set constructor.

```
search_term = '4'
data = {'h':['123','4'], 'm':['456','4'], 'a':['123','4']}
result = set(k for k,v in data.items() if search_term in v)
assert result == {'h', 'm', 'a'}
```

Comment: Since the elements of the set are keys from the dictionary, wouldn't a list be sufficient (since we know the elements are unique)?

Comment: I would think so, yes. But the OP's question clearly displays a set as the result.

Comment: @pault why would you prefer a list of unique elements over a set?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen just asking. I initially thought there might have been some extra overhead for a set vs. a list, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

> **What about without loop ?**

Everyone is going to give you loop soution , let's try something different :

data is:

```
your_data = {'h':['123','4'], 'm':['456','4'], 'a':['123','4']}
```

> One line without loop:

```
print(set(filter(lambda y:y,map(lambda x:x if '4' in your_data.get(x) else None,your_data))))
```

output:

```
{'a', 'm', 'h'}
```

> Best way is use a function :

```
def search_values(x,dict_data):
    final_list=[]
    for key,value in dict_data.items():
        if x in value:
            final_list.append(key)

    return set(final_list)

print(search_values('4',your_data))
```

output:

```
{'a', 'm', 'h'}
```

Comment: your one-liner only works if all of the keys contain the search term, otherwise the result has `None` in it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I have fixed it. Take a look.