# Python loops:  Precise way to handle mapping matching lists

Tags: python

A function returns two lists which are logically mapped **one-to-one**. Suppose

```
name = ["facebook", "twitter", "myspace"]
hits = [4000, 2500, 1800]
```

Therefore, hits for facebook are 4000, twitter 2500, and myspace 2500.

**I want to convert these two separate lists into a list of dictionaries** like

```
[
  {name: 'facebook',data: [4000]},
  {name: 'twitter',data: [2500]},
  {name: 'myspace',data: [1800]}
]
```

**My solution** to do this is:

```
data = [
    {"name":l, "data":[v]}
    for idx1, l in enumerate(labels)
    for idx2, v in enumerate(values)
    if idx1 == idx2
    ]
```

Is there a more **elegant** way of dealing with logical one-to-one mapping or is my solution precise?

Comment: [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is the little nugget of elegance you're looking for.

Comment: Does your example really embody a one-to-one relationship?  Isn't it possible that both *twitter* and *myspace* have the same number of hits?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: the question illustrates a logical mapping. Meaning name [0] is mapped to hits[0] and so on

Comment: @mangobug Then your answer is as simple as ``name2hits = dict(zip(name, hits))``.  There is no need for separate *name* and *data* fields, nor for a list of values.  Also, the term "one-to-one" can be dropped (as that term implies an injective mathematical function).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do:

```
[{"name": n, "data": [h]} for n, h in zip(name, hits)]
```

While this does what you asked for, there's probably more data structure here than you really need. Consider:

```
>>> dict(zip(name, hits))
{'twitter': 2500, 'myspace': 1800, 'facebook': 4000}
```

This provides the same data set in an easier-to-access data structure.

Comment: This is what the OP asked for, but it is *far* from being the right data structure for his task.  The *name* and *data* key fields are a waste and so is the inner list which isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest and fastest way to handle one-to-one relationships is to make two dictionaries:

```
>>> name = ["facebook", "twitter", "myspace"]
>>> hits = [4000, 2500, 1800]
>>> name2hits = dict(zip(name, hits))
>>> hit2name = dict(zip(hits, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar but not exactly the same as [Efficient bidirectional hash table in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python)

You should just use two dictionaries, and when you make an update, apply the update to both.

Also, there is a logical inconsistency here: Either your function is not one-to-one, or you have no need for keeping `data: [...]` in a list since there can only be one value.

If you really need to convert it into a list of dictionaries, use `zip` as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600534/711085