# How do I create a pythonic bi-directional lookup

Tags: python

I need a bi-direction lookup, and to keep the code DRY I don't want to write the values twice, the simplest thing I can come up with is to create the reverse lookup from the original like this:

```
>>> lookup1 =  {1:'one', 2:'two'}
>>> lookup2 = dict([(v,k) for (k,v) in lookup1.items()])
>>> lookup2.get('two')
2
```

But is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

The dicts are not very large (dozens of items at most) so performance is not the paramount concern.

(I am restricted to v2.6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python bidirectional mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282997/python-bidirectional-mapping)

Comment: also you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python

Comment: "to keep the code DRY I don't want to write the values twice" - how is your solution going to keep the code DRY? The right way(TM) would be to encapsulate lookup and reverse-lookup functionality in one object, and hide how it's implemented.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, the thing is encapsulated, it's the implementation that I am asking about.

Comment: You don't need '[' and ']' when creating the lookup2 dict.