# Best implementation of dual-side dict in Python

Tags: python

I mean a dictionary where of you could get the value by key or the key by value depending on what you need.

Comment: Use two dicts .

Comment: What is your final goal / use case? Think of issues like duplicated keys/values. There are already similar answers on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [bidict package](https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) which provides a bidirectional map. The syntax looks as follows (taken from the documentation):

```
>>> from bidict import bidict
>>> element_by_symbol = bidict(H='hydrogen')
>>> element_by_symbol
bidict({'H': 'hydrogen'})
>>> element_by_symbol['H']
'hydrogen'


>>> element_by_symbol.inv
bidict({'hydrogen': 'H'})
>>> element_by_symbol.inv['hydrogen']
'H'
>>> element_by_symbol.inv.inv is element_by_symbol
True
```

Or you can implement it yourself, for example using one of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python).