# python: couple of values to be called reciprocally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a set (potentially a very large number) of values generated at random, which I need to have quick access to
and so from both sides. meaning:

take a tuple:

```
(133: 42)
```

one way:

```
getIDfromValue(42)
>>>133
```

the other:

```
getValuefromID(133)
>>>42
```

the way i have been doing this so far is by making two dictionnaries and accessing one or the other depending the need.
like:

```
values = {42:133, ...}
ids = {133:42, ...}

values[42]
>>>133
ids[133]
>>>42
```

but that doesn't feel quite nor right nor efficient.
how would one do this?

(subsidiary question: is a argument of dictionary accessed directly in memory, or is the dictionary iterated?)

thanks a lot

Comment: Also [Efficient bidirectional hash table in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python)

Comment: Can ids and values overlap?

Comment: You could either use the bidirectional solution @pault provided or look over some of the data structures in the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html) part of the standard library. If you truly need a bidirectional hash table then use pault's link, but you might be able to reformat the problem to work with an existing data structure.

Comment: these are great references, which I didn't find before. thanks a lot.
in my understanding of these dict subclassing examples, they always involve the creation of a sub-dictionary. 
hence, the main gain in using such structure is readability. isn't it?
isn't it very similar to my two dictionaries solution, only encapsulated?

Comment: @bphi sorry, what do you mean by overlap?