# Reverse lookup dict of tuples, or use a different data structure?

Tags: python

I currently have a dictionary of tuples like this:

```py
d = {
    0: ('f', 'farm'),
    1: ('m', 'mountain'),
    2: ('h', 'house'),
    3: ('t', 'forest'),
    4: ('d', 'desert')
}
```

It's been working fine until I realized that I need to be able to do a reverse lookup, so given `'f'` return `0`, or given `'m'` return `1`

I know that's possible here by creating lists of the keys and values in the dict and cross-referencing them to find the position of the key, but that seems counter productive. I was wondering if there's a different data structure that would be better suited.

All the relationships here are one-to-one. `0` will always map to `f`, and `f` will always map to `0`

Answer (score 2):

There are already similar questions that you could use as a starting point.

[How to implement an efficient bidirectional hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/how-to-implement-an-efficient-bidirectional-hash-table)
[Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping)

In your specific case, the dict in its current form may be pointless. Dicts with integer keys starting from zero are just inefficient lists, but lists already have a reverse lookup method called `index`.

So what you could do is:

```
places_order = ['f', 'm', 'h', 't', 'd']
```

and then use `places_order.index(some_letter)` to get the corresponding integer.
This is an O(n) operation, so I'm assuming you don't need to perform these lookups millions of times with high performance. (Otherwise, especially if the real `places_order` is a long list, consider `dict(zip(places_order, range(len(places_order))))`.)

In addition, you could keep a map for the abbreviations of place names.

```
abbreviations = {
    'f': 'farm',
    'm': 'mountain',
    'h': 'house',
    't': 'forest',
    'd': 'desert'
}
```

It's hard to say more without knowing any specifics about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A most straightforward search would be:

```py
def search(dictionary, word):
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        if word in value:
            return key
```

This could then be used as:

```py
>>> search(d, 'h')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the use-case, but if you are not looking for a built-in python what about [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.Series(['farm', 'mountain', 'house', 'forest', 'desert'],index = ['f', 'm', 'h', 't', 'd'])
```

so both `d[0]` and `d['f']` will output `'farm'`, `d.index[0]` will give `'f'` and `d.index.get_loc('f')` will give `0`.

For the case of built-ins see @timgeb's answer or consider a sort of `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict like this:

```
abs = {
'f': 'farm',
'm': 'mountain',
'h': 'house',
't': 'forest',
'd': 'desert'
}
```

when you need to reverse loop:

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(abs.items()):
    print(i, key, value)  # 0 f farm
```

when you want items by index:

```
list(abs.items())[i]  # ('f', 'farm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
d = {
    0: ('f', 'farm'),
    1: ('m', 'mountain'),
    2: ('h', 'house'),
    3: ('t', 'forest'),
    4: ('d', 'desert')
}
for key, value in d.items():
    if 'h' in value:
        print (key)
        break
```