# Is it possible to reverse lookup / invert a dictionary IF the value is a tuple and you only have a single value from the tuple?

Tags: python

Say I have a dictionary:

```py
d = {
    0: ('f', 'farm'),
    1: ('m', 'mountain'),
    2: ('h', 'house'),
    3: ('t', 'forest'),
    4: ('d', 'desert')
}
```

and the only information I'm given is the value `h`. How can I retrieve `2` - the key that corresponds to `h` - from the dictionary?

In other words, I don't have the whole tuple `('h', 'house')` to do a proper reverse lookup, I only have the `h`. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: What happens if you have repeated `'h'` values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse lookup dict of tuples, or use a different data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188105/reverse-lookup-dict-of-tuples-or-use-a-different-data-structure)

Comment: If it's an infrequent operation where you don't need to build a permanent reverse lookup table, `next((idx for (idx, entry) in d if entry[0] == 'h'), None)` should be okay.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v[0] == 'h':
        print(k)
```