# Can't check if key belongs to values

Tags: python, dictionary

The `short()` function below doesn't work. `full()` works completely fine. Is there a solution, or do I have to make another directory where key and value are swapped?

```
import random

elements = {"Sc":"Scandium",
           "Ti":"Titanium",
           "V":"Vanadium",
           "Cr":"Chromium",
           "Mn":"Manganum",
           "Fe":"Ferrum"}


def short():
    question = random.choice(list(elements.values()))
    print(question)
    answer = input("What is the short name of this element?: ")
    if answer == elements[question]:
        print("Right")


def full():
    question = random.choice(list(elements.keys()))
    print(question)
    answer = input("What is the full name of this element?: ")
    if answer == elements[question]:
        print("Right")


mode = input("Do you want to guess the short or full name? (sh/fu): ").lower()

if mode == "sh":
    short()

elif mode == "fu":
    full()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement an efficient bidirectional hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/how-to-implement-an-efficient-bidirectional-hash-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my mind. You don't need a reverse `dict`.

Just structure `short()` slightly differently:

```py
import random

elements = {"Sc":"Scandium",
           "Ti":"Titanium",
           "V":"Vanadium",
           "Cr":"Chromium",
           "Mn":"Manganum",
           "Fe":"Ferrum"}

def short():
    question = random.choice(list(elements.keys()))
    print(elements[question])
    answer = input("What is the short name of this element?: ")
    if answer == question:
        print("Right")

def full():
    question = random.choice(list(elements.keys()))
    print(question)
    answer = input("What is the full name of this element?: ")
    if answer == elements[question]:
        print("Right")

mode = input("Do you want to guess the short or full name? (sh/fu): ").lower()

if mode == "sh":
    short()

elif mode == "fu":
    full()
```

`short()` now selects a key at random just like `full()`, but asks the question in terms of the long name which is easily accessible in the forwards direction.