# Pool objects, keep reference to pool, make illegal states irrepresentable

Tags: data-structures

I have a number of objects and I'd like to "pool" them, i.e., put them into lists or sets such that

- every object appears in at most one list, and
- every object knows which list it's in.

In Python, I could do

```py
# create objects

pool1 = [obj1, obj5, obj6]
pool2 = [obj3]
pool3 = [obj8, obj7]

obj1.pool = pool1
obj2.pool = None
obj3.pool = pool2
obj4.pool = None
obj5.pool = pool1
obj6.pool = pool1
obj7.pool = pool3
obj8.pool = pool3
```

This works, but has the disadvantage that the data structure can represent illegal states, e.g.,

```py
pool1 = [obj1]
pool2 = []

obj1.pool = pool2
```

or

```py
pool1 = [obj1]
pool2 = [obj1]

obj1.pool = pool1
```

Is there a more fitting data structure for this?

Comment: This looks like a use-case for [How to implement an efficient bidirectional dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/how-to-implement-an-efficient-bidirectional-hash-table)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a more fitting data structure for this, as you need the association to work in two directions (from object to list, from list to object).

The best is probably to encapsulate this logic in a class and require that the caller uses only the provided methods to manipulate the data structure.

In Python that could look like this:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pool = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Pools():
    def __init__(self):
        self._pools = {}

    def assign(self, poolid, obj):
        if poolid not in self._pools:
            self._pools[poolid] = set()
        if obj.pool is not None:
            self._pools[obj.pool].discard(obj)
        if poolid is not None:
            self._pools[poolid].add(obj)
        obj.pool = poolid

    def unassign(self, obj):
        self.assign(None, obj)
        
    def content(self, poolid):
        return list(self._pools[poolid])


# demo
a = Node("a")
b = Node("b")
c = Node("c")

pools = Pools()
pools.assign(0, a)
pools.assign(0, b)
pools.assign(5, c)
pools.assign(3, a)
pools.assign(3, c)
pools.unassign(b)

print(pools.content(0))  # []
print(pools.content(3))  # ['a', 'c']
print(pools.content(5))  # []
print(a.pool) # 3
print(b.pool) # None
print(c.pool) # 3
```

You could improve on this and make `Pools` a subclass of `dict`, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using class `bidict` from [How to implement an efficient bidirectional hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21894086/3080723)

```py
class bidict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(bidict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.inverse = {}
        for key, value in self.items():
            self.inverse.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            self.inverse[self[key]].remove(key)
        super(bidict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.inverse.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.inverse.setdefault(self[key], []).remove(key)
        if self[key] in self.inverse and not self.inverse[self[key]]:
            del self.inverse[self[key]]
        super(bidict, self).__delitem__(key)
```

```py
data = [('pool1', ['obj1', 'obj5', 'obj6']), ('pool2', ['obj3']), ('pool3', ['obj8', 'obj7'])]
d = bidict((obj, poolname) for poolname, pool in data for obj in pool)

print(d['obj3'])
# pool2

print(d.inverse['pool1'])
# ['obj1', 'obj5', 'obj6']   

print(d)
# {'obj1': 'pool1', 'obj5': 'pool1', 'obj6': 'pool1', 'obj3': 'pool2', 'obj8': 'pool3', 'obj7': 'pool3'}

print(d.inverse)
# {'pool1': ['obj1', 'obj5', 'obj6'], 'pool2': ['obj3'], 'pool3': ['obj8', 'obj7']}
```

Note that `d` maps each key to only one value, while `d.inverse` maps each value to a list of key, hence the choice to use `obj` as the key and `pool` as the value rather than the other way around.

This requires the objs and pools to be hashable; if they are not, but they have a `idx` or `name` field that is hashable and can be used as a unique identifier, then use this field in the bidict.