# build a dictionary for find key by value

Tags: python

dictionary is usually good for find value by key,but find key by value is pretty slow

```
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    if v = myValue:
        return k
```

is there already a data structure that make both key->value and ke

Comment: I'm against this being a duplicate of [Two way/reverse map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map) - that is a special case where keys and values never are the same, at least from its accepted answer. In the general case, this question's [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12527752/321973) is much better

Comment: This question is more a duplicate of [Efficient bidirectional hash table in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python) than the other one due to the latter's restrictions

Comment: meta.SO discussion: [How to correctly treat fupes (=fake dupes)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182141/146482)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [bidict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict):

```
>>> husbands2wives = bidict({'john': 'jackie'})
>>> husbands2wives['john'] # the forward mapping is just like with dict
'jackie'
>>> husbands2wives[:'jackie'] # use slice for the inverse mapping
'john'
```

Comment: Do you know if this is faster than just using an inverted dict (as Martjin suggests), or does it just sugar for the same?

Comment: @hayden: bidict stores the forward and inverted dicts and provides syntactic sugar, so speedwise it's the same provided you created your inverted dict once.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not entirely correct, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793526/is-there-a-better-way-to-store-a-twoway-dictionary-than-storing-its-inverse-sepa?lq=1#comment24202891_16793526) the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/jab/bidict/src/8a2eb8d16607395954175c389ed4c7b1721c074e/bidict.py?at=default#cl-437) contains some checks that make bidict slightly slower than two pure dicts. Though for pure read access, `husbands2wives._fwd['john']` and `husband2swives._bwd['jackie']` would provide the same speed

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Unless you are running this in a 150000 item loop, the difference is going to be minimal. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I perfectly agree, and read-/maintainability is more import than those few milliseconds. It's just something to keep in mind _if_ speed is crucial; and in that case explicitly using an inverse dictionary would probably be better. But in 99.9% of cases I'd say bidict is the best way

Comment: The sugar `[:val]` and `~dict` are not available anymore. Instead, go with `bidict.inv[val]` and `bidict.inv`

Answer (score 5):

Just create an inverted mapping:

```
from collections import defaultdict
inverted = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
    inverted[v].append(k)
```

Note that the above code handles duplicate values; `inverted[v]` returns a *list* of keys that hold that value.

If your values are also unique, a simple dict can be used instead of `defaultdict`:

```
inverted = { v: k for k, v in dictionary.iteritems() }
```

or, in python 3, where `items()` is a dictionary view:

```
inverted = { v: k for k, v in dictionary.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
revdict = {v:k for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

(Python 2 use `.iteritems()` instead)