# Python: encode/decode a string in Django

Tags: python, django, string, encoding

If I have a string `FOOBAR-efkem4x-dnj3mn-efjn2j-lf4m2l` (in this format) I need to convert into a shorter string consisting of just numerical values `[0-9]` so I can put it as a unique number in the URL for my Django project.

So that string should be converted into something like `324982984829` (can be higher or lower length, doesn't matter as long it is all numeric). Decoding `324982984829` should get me back to `FOOBAR-efkem4x-dnj3mn-efjn2j-lf4m2l`.

The end numerical value should be unique for every unique string.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Look at https://gist.github.com/sekondus/4322469

Comment: If you happen to want obscurity, not security, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password

Comment: You can't encode the string to a shorter numerical string, but if you want a longer why not simply translate every character to its `ord` and add some 0's if needed for padding (if you are using only regular characters, 3 numerals per letter will be enough)

Comment: This is actually called encoding, not encryption (encryption requires a key to be used). tbrisker comment makes a good starting point. It may not be optimal though, you should create a special mapping from character to decimal value for that (that's tricky though, so if ordinals suffice, go for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a two-way [dictonary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map) which is a nice way to do that task. An working example looks like that:

```
class TwoWayDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Remove any previous connections with these values
        if key in self:
            del self[key]
        if value in self:
            del self[value]
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        dict.__setitem__(self, value, key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, self[key])
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)

    def __len__(self):
        """Returns the number of connections"""
        # The int() call is for Python 3
        return int(dict.__len__(self) / 2)

d = TwoWayDict()
for i in range(10):
    d["FOOBAR-efkem4x-dnj3mn-efjn2j-lf4m2l"+str(i)] = str(i)



for i in range(10):
    print d['FOOBAR-efkem4x-dnj3mn-efjn2j-lf4m2l'+str(i)], "<->", d[str(i)]
```

Of course you can use any other numerical hash aswell.