# Convenient way to create a map for list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

For a list of tuples with unique values such as:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

I would like to create a map:

```
b = {}
for t in a:
    for tt in t:
        b[tt] = t

>>> {1: (1, 2), 2: (1, 2), 3: (3, 4), 4: (3, 4), 5: (5, 6), 6: (5, 6)}
```

Is there a nicer/convenient way to achieve this without the explicit for loop? One way might be to use `dict.update` although this could get ugly with many items in the tuple:

```
[(b.update({t1: (t1, t2)}), b.update({t2: (t1, t2)})) for t1, t2 in a]
```

Comment: Related: [Efficient bidirectional hash table in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python), [Two way/reverse map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map)

Comment: Thanks that is basically what I am after, a poor mans bidirectional hash in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> {i: tup for tup in a for i in tup}
{1: (1, 2), 2: (1, 2), 3: (3, 4), 4: (3, 4), 5: (5, 6), 6: (5, 6)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
flatten = chain.from_iterable

a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
d = dict(flatten(((k, (k, v)), (v, (k, v))) for k, v in a))

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehensions:

```
{**{k: (k, v) for k, v in a}, **{v: (k, v) for k, v in a}}
```

Comment: I assumed 3. I'm also getting syntax error in 3.4, but I recall it's allowed in newer Python.