# Better way to sort list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks like this one:

```
big_list = [['12345', 'azs'], ['ABC', 'something'], ['tgrgd', 'ABC'], ['something', '12345']
```

The lists inside big_list always contain only 2 strings.

I want to sort it as follows:

```
big_list (or new_list) = [['tgrgd', 'ABC'], ['ABC', 'something'], ['something', '12345'], ['12345', 'azs']]
```

The second string of a list is equal to the first of next list.
It is impossible to have the same string in more than 2 lists, so that won't be a problem.

I am currently addressing the problem by counting occurrences of each string to find the first and last items and then looping through my list to sort it, but I know this is a wrong approach and would like to improve it.

Comment: Please post some code showing what you tried so far?

Comment: Anyway I would try using some [reverse map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map).

Comment: How do you determine which one will come first?

Comment: Use dictionaries. Put the first string as a key and the second as value. That way it will be super fast finding the next string.