# Get key Name with the value from Python Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the key with the known values ..I can easily find the value with the key using d['Key1']  but suppose if values are like provided below and is known how to get the key name using the value ..

Example .. If I know there is `k1` as value how to get the key of it from dict ?

```
d = {'key1':'k1',"Key2":"k2"}
```

Comment: You have to iterate through the dictionary until you get a matching value. You could try looking at something like a [bidirectional map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map) or simply create another dict in reverse

Comment: @roganjosh ok , there is no simple way it means ?

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks ! Seems I missed that post .

Comment: @roganjosh Thank You !

Comment: `dict(map(reversed, d.items()))['k1']` -> `'key1'`. Assumes that your values are hashable and unique.

Comment: @timgeb This is excellent . :) Thank You for the help !

Comment: @timgeb or just `{v: k for k, v in d.items()}` is a bit more readable?