# How create mapping between two group elements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping

Consider I have two groups of string elements (unnecessary string - just for the example):
"strA1, strA2, strA3" and "strB1, strB2, strB3".
I'd like to map elements from the first list with elements from the second list into unique pairs by known law that I can find element in the second list by element in the first list and visa versa.
I know three methods to do it.

**Method 1.: Create a map**

```
{'strA1':'strB1', 'strA2':'strB2', 'strA3':'strB3'}
```

In this case I can find an element from the second list just by key. But if I want to find element from the first list I have to iterate through all dictionary keys.

**Method 2.: Create two maps:**

```
{'strA1':'strB1', 'strA2':'strB2', 'strA3':'strB3'}

{'strB1':'strA1', 'strB2':'strA2', 'strB3':'strA3'}
```

In this case I can find an element by key in both lists but I have to keep two maps for that.

**Method 3:** **Create meaningful indexes (manually or with enum) and use a special parameter to select an element from the pair in a tuple:**

```
from enum import Enum
Index = Enum('Index', ['PAIR_A1B1', 'PAIR_A2B2', 'PAIR_A3B3'], start=0)  #understandable names
 #direction
A2B = 0
B2A = 1   
mappingList = [('strA1','strB1'), ('strA2','strB2'), ('strA3','strB3')]
print(mappingList[Index.PAIR_A1B1.value][A2B]) # I get my mapped string here
```

Are there another methods?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456373/9608759) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [`bidict`](https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library too:

```
from bidict import bidict

group1=["strA1", "strA2", "strA3"]   
group2=["strB1", "strB2", "strB3"]
    
dc=dict(zip(group1,group2))   #we create the dictionary by using zip to create the tuples and then cast it to a dict
    
newdc= bidict(dc)             #we create the bi-directional dictionary

print(newdc['strA1'])
print(newdc.inverse['strB1'])
```

Output:

```
strB1
strA1
```

Comment: Very nice! Powerful and neatly documented.

Answer (score 1):

The forward and reverse mappings are probably your best option.  Here is a way that you could access them via a single object (subclass of dictionary with a reversed dictionary added).

Obviously it will still need to allocate the memory, although the two dictionaries will use references to the same objects contained within them, rather than duplicated objects.

```
class Map(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._reversed = dict((v, k) for k, v in self.items())
        if len(self) != len(self._reversed):
            raise ValueError("values not unique")

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if v in self._reversed:
            raise ValueError("attempted item assignment would create many-to-one mapping")        
        if k in self:
            # reassigning - need to delete reversed key first
            del self._reversed[self[k]]  # or just "del self[k]" here
        super().__setitem__(k, v)
        self._reversed[v] = k

    def __delitem__(self, k):
        del self._reversed[self[k]]
        super().__delitem__(k)

    def get_reversed(self, v):
        return self._reversed[v]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = Map({'strA1':'strB1', 'strA2':'strB2', 'strA3':'strB3'})

    a["strA4"] = "strB4"
    a["strA5"] = "strB5"

    # in each of forward and reversed direction, test
    # one of the pairs that we started with, and one of 
    # the pairs that we added afterwards

    for k in "strA2", "strA4":
        print(a[k])

    for k in "strB3", "strB5":
        print(a.get_reversed(k))
```

gives:

```
strB2
strB4
strA3
strA5
```

It would need