# Python Making two string correlate to each other

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to make it so say if the two strings are `"Danny"` and `"DeVito"` And if you do something, like if you search for `"Danny"` then it will return `"Danny"` and `"DeVito"` and vise-versa. I thought about dictionaries, but I'm not sure how to use those.

### EDIT: Extra info

I was also wondering if there was a way to search in all of the pairs and see if a string is in it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Look at bidict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613121/1170207

Answer (score 1):

Python has a great module for this called bidict

https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-usage.html

```
>>> element_by_symbol = bidict(H='hydrogen')
>>> element_by_symbol.inverse['helium'] = 'He'
>>> del element_by_symbol.inverse['hydrogen']
>>> element_by_symbol
bidict({'He': 'helium'})
```

(Example code from https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-usage.html)